# couchdbbackup command not found in cron job

Tags: bash, shell, couchdb, cloudant

I am trying to execute a cronjob.sh file using cronjob in mac machine.
When I run my cronjob using `./cronJob.sh` it works fine but when I schedule it using cronjob it shows couchdbbackup command not found.

Here is my script code looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "backup start"
couchbackup --url "https://username:password@dburl" --db db_name --log /Users/Demo/Documents/Backup/db-`date -u "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"`.log > /Users/Demo/Documents/Backup/db_Prod-`date -u "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"`.txt
echo "backup finish"
```

I am using couchDb for taking db backup.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cloudant/couchbackup
This is package is already installed in machine.

Please let me know what is going wrong.

Comment: everywhere set absolute paths for commands

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are likely facing is that couchbackup is not in the $PATH of the environment given to the cron execution.

The answer is to provide the full path to your executable couchbackup.